# Authentication via Twitter with pac4j in Vaadin 14.2 application: "code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."

Tags: twitter, spring-security, vaadin, pac4j

I'm trying to integrate a Twitter authentication (ideally SSO) in a Vaadin application. For this I created a Vaadin application from scratch and tried to integrate pac4j (see following steps). Unfortunately I get error "code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you." despite valid email/password combination. Any ideas how to get this to work?

1. Download a Vaadin 14.2 project from https://vaadin.com/start/v14
2. Run Application.java and visit localhost:8080 works fine.
3. Extend pom.xml with pac4j for Spring Boot:

   ```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.pac4j/spring-security-pac4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-pac4j</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
   ```
4. Extend pom.xml with pac4j for Twitter client:

   ```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.pac4j/pac4j-oauth -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>pac4j-oauth</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
   ```
5. Extend pom.xml with Spring Security

   ```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
   ```
6. Create class Pac4jConfig like in the Spring Security example in this presentation http://www.pac4j.org/gettingstarted.html

   ```
    import org.pac4j.core.config.Config;
    import org.pac4j.oauth.client.TwitterClient;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    @Configuration
    public class Pac4jConfig {
        @Bean
        public Config config() {
            TwitterClient twitterClient = new TwitterClient();
            Config config = new Config("http://localhost:8080", twitterClient);
            return config;
        }
    }
   ```
7. Create class SecurityConfig like in the Spring Security example in this presentation http://www.pac4j.org/gettingstarted.html

   ```
    import org.pac4j.core.config.Config;
    import org.pac4j.springframework.security.web.CallbackFilter;
    import org.pac4j.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilter;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
    import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;

    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig {

        @Configuration
        @Order(1)
        public static class TwitterWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter
                extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
            @Autowired
            private Config config;

            protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                final SecurityFilter filter = new SecurityFilter(config, "TwitterClient");
                http.antMatcher("/twitter/**").addFilterBefore(filter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
            }
        }

        @Configuration
        public static class DefaultWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter
                extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
            @Autowired
            private Config config;

            protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                final CallbackFilter callbackFilter = new CallbackFilter(config);
                http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll().and().addFilterBefore(callbackFilter,
                        BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
            }
        }
    }
   ```
8. Create class TwitterTestApplication like class "Application" in the Spring Security example in this presentation http://www.pac4j.org/gettingstarted.html

   ```
    import java.util.Map;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    @Controller
    public class TwitterTestApplication {
        @RequestMapping("/twitter/index.html")
        public String twitter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                Map<String, Object> map) {
            return "Hello world";
        }
    }
   ```
9. Calling http://localhost:8080/twitter/index.html lead to this error:

   ```
    There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
    key cannot be blank
    org.pac4j.core.exception.TechnicalException: key cannot be blank
        at org.pac4j.core.util.CommonHelper.assertTrue(CommonHelper.java:107)
        [...]
   ```
10. Extending the constructor call of the TwitterClient by my credentials (which work fine when I copy/paste them at twitter.com) and allowing emails:

    ```
    TwitterClient twitterClient = new TwitterClient("[my-email]", "[my-password]", true);
    ```
11. Calling http://localhost:8080/twitter/index.html lead to this error:

    ```
    There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
    com.github.scribejava.core.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is incorrect. Can't extract token and secret from this: '{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}'
    org.pac4j.core.exception.TechnicalException: com.github.scribejava.core.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is incorrect. Can't extract token and secret from this: '{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}'
        at org.pac4j.oauth.redirect.OAuth10RedirectionActionBuilder.getRedirectionAction(OAuth10RedirectionActionBuilder.java:62)
        at org.pac4j.core.client.IndirectClient.getRedirectionAction(IndirectClient.java:109)
        at org.pac4j.core.engine.DefaultSecurityLogic.redirectToIdentityProvider(DefaultSecurityLogic.java:224)
        at org.pac4j.core.engine.DefaultSecurityLogic.perform(DefaultSecurityLogic.java:157)
        at org.pac4j.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:73)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    ```

Comment: You cannot use username and password for authentication to Twitter in a third party app, you need to use OAuth and include your consumer API key and secret.

Comment: Oh right, there's an "apply for a developer account"-button at https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/developer-portal/overview - thanks. :-)